# beautiful soup getting tag.id

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I'm attempting to get a list of div ids from a page. When I print out the attributes, I get the ids listed.

```
for tag in soup.find_all(class_="bookmark blurb group") :
  print(tag.attrs)
```

results in:

```
{'id': 'bookmark_8199633', 'role': 'article', 'class': ['bookmark', 'blurb', 'group']}
{'id': 'bookmark_7744613', 'role': 'article', 'class': ['bookmark', 'blurb', 'group']}
{'id': 'bookmark_7338591', 'role': 'article', 'class': ['bookmark', 'blurb', 'group']}
{'id': 'bookmark_7338535', 'role': 'article', 'class': ['bookmark', 'blurb', 'group']}
{'id': 'bookmark_4530078', 'role': 'article', 'class': ['bookmark', 'blurb', 'group']}
```

So I know there ARE ids. However, when I print out tag.id instead, I just get a list of "None". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can access tag’s attributes by treating the tag like a dictionary ([documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes)):

```
for tag in soup.find_all(class_="bookmark blurb group") :
    print tag.get('id')
```

The reason `tag.id` didn't work is that it is equivalent to `tag.find('id')`, which results into `None` since there is no `id` tag found ([documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names)).

Answer (score 3):

This solution lists all tags with ids in a page , It might be helpful too.

```
tags = page_soup.find_all()
for tag in tags:
    if 'id' in tag.attrs:
        print(tag.name,tag['id'],sep='->')
```