# get the numbers within the following HTML tag via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

can i get the numbers within the following HTML tag via beautifulsoup ?

```
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599656" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="0"></tr>
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599657" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="1"></tr>
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599644" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="2"></tr>
```

Python Code I've tried

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_code = """"
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599656" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="0"></tr>
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599657" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="1"></tr>
<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599644" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="2"></tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code,'html.parser')
rows = soup.findAll("tr", {"id" : re.compile('tr_*\d')})
print rows
```

Expected output

```
1599656
1599657
1599644
```

Comment: Sure you can! What have you tried?

Comment: sorry dear, forget put the code i've tried, will put next time, thanks ! @Sayse

Comment: No worries, always worth adding it retrospectively too which I see you have. Removed downvote.

Comment: dear, thanks ! @Sayse

Comment: dear, slightly difference with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24962673/beautiful-soup-getting-tag-id since I just have id one reference only, but anyway, thanks for your comments

Comment: Apart from accepted solution you can also try `rows = [tr.get('id').split('tr_')[-1] for tr in soup.findAll("tr")]`

Comment: thanks a lot, dear !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup=BeautifulSoup('<tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599656" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="0"></tr><tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599657" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="1"></tr><tr align="center" height="15" id="tr_1599644" bgcolor="#ffffff" index="2"></tr>')

lines=soup.find_all('tr')

for line in lines:print(re.findall('\d+',line['id'])[0])
```

Please try once on your own next time. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the id attribute follows the pattern tr_XXXXXXX. This code will work on it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_code,'html.parser')
for t in soup.findAll('tr'):
    print(t['id'][3:])
```

#### Output

> 1599656
>   1599657
>   1599644

variable `html_code` contains the piece of html code you posted with your question